# HBase data persistence

Tags: java, hadoop, cloud, storage, hbase

I have been trying to understand how Hbase works. Specifically - how data is stored to disk.

I have read articles online and two of which helped me were -

http://th30z.blogspot.com/2011/02/hbase-io-hfile.html?spref=tw

and

http://www.slashdocs.com/iyxmiz/hfile-a-block-indexed-file-format-to-store-sorted-key-value-pairs.html

I still have some questions, may be because I didn't understand HBase very well. Here's what I get from what I read - Every transaction - (Put/Get/Delete) is saved as KeyValue in the memstore and then written off to StoreFiles/Hfiles on flushing. The data that is stored on the disk is actually these HFiles.

Now, the structure of the KeyValue class specifies - the data that needs to be stored(if any), key and the type of operation (Put/Get/Delete). The data blocks in the HFiles themselves represent the KeyValues (with the "rowkey" being a part of the Key).

As I see it, when these KeyValues are persisted, its more like saving a transaction rather than making changes to existing data. When does a transaction of this kind be processed/consolidated to result in a row. I assumed that it could be during the compaction process but then, I don't know how the requests to the data which is written to a HFile but not compacted are handled.

I also did not understand it when the articles said "Before a KeyValue pair is written to a block, the order of the key must be bigger than the previous one."

I think I have made some wrong assumptions in the process of understanding HBase.

Can someone help me understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Before a KeyValue pair is written to a block, the order ..."

Yes, new data could be treated as transaction, but they are of the same data format/structure as that after compaction. Which means, these "transaction" co-exists with old data and has no difference with the old data except the timestamp.

When requests comes, hbase will look at both previous data and new data (the "transaction" you mentioned), but new data whose timestamp is newer will be returned.

> "Before a KeyValue pair is written to a block, the order of the key must be bigger than the previous one"

I guess the point here is, before block is written to disk, keys are sorted in the memstore (a memory cache) to make sure "the order of the key must be bigger than the previous one".

Comment: My question is.... if they are saved as transactions, say we have two transactions (2 PUTS) with the same column family and the second PUT updates the column value of the one posted by the first. Now, when HBase receives a request for a particular rowkey, is it going to consolidate both these KeyValues to give out a result?

Comment: Right. HBase will consolidate both these KeyValues to give out the result.

Comment: Okay. And the deletes will be optimized during the compaction to remove the preceding KeyValues for that rowkey? shouldn't the statement be - "Before a KeyValue pair is written to a block, the order of the key must be no less than the previous one" ?

Comment: Right. 1) DELETE will append data just as PUT does, but with a tag 'delete' while PUT is with tag 'put'. So, DELETE data will be skipped when requesting. Compaction will remove the 'delete' data.  2) yes, and you could refer to the [book section](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#dm.sort) for details.